# Prevent display password on wp-login.php

Tags: login, wp-login-form

In wp-login.php i want send password salted SHA256 on password. So i can avoid the security data exposed.

see the screenshot where pwd is not encrypted so how can make made encryption so should not be display the password even in inspect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to use SSL.

However, you could use javascript to encrypt the password somehow before sending it to the server, but this isn't going to offer much more protection because anyone looking at the data could just as easily unencrypt the password. Here's more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291495/how-to-encrypt-form-data.

Use SSL ;)

Comment: Yes we have https in our server. which file we need to change ?

Comment: Then you’re completely safe. This is a standard practise throughout the internet :)

Comment: is their any tutorial or link where can we look into it